# Should I rely on require statements from other contracts in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Let's say that my contract is interacting with different contract.

The contract I'm interacting with has a require statement for example that will revert if you don't have enough tokens.

Now I'm not sure if I should add the same require statement to my contract. Would it be vulnerable if I relied just on the require statement from the other contract?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you invoke the external contract.

If you use the contract/interface type object and named function (see `getExternalValueNamed()`), it reverts the main transaction.

But if you use the low-level call (see `getExternalValueCall()`), it does not revert the main transaction.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract ExternalContract {
    function getValue() public {
        revert();
    }
}

contract Caller {
    address externalContractAddress;

    constructor(address _externalContractAddress) {
        externalContractAddress = _externalContractAddress;
    }

    function getExternalValueNamed() public {
        // causes the main transaction to revert
        ExternalContract(externalContractAddress).getValue();
    }

    function getExternalValueCall() public {
        // does not revert the main transaction
        externalContractAddress.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("getValue()")
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.